# Check the java website is available or not using C#

Tags: java, c#, jsp

I want my program in C# to check if a website is online or not. I have done for an ASP.net website and is working successfully. But for JSP with https protocol its not working and throwing `500 internal error`. Below is the code I am using

```
    HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://xyz/abc/temp.jsp");

        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = null;
        }
        if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            response.Close();
            return true;
        }
```

> Error : [System.Net.WebException] = {"The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error."}

Can any one help me how can I perform for the Java website with Https protocol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a server error. So the site is "online", but it returned an error page. Not much your tool can do here, expect maybe playing with the URL to avoid the error. Look at the page in a browser to see what is happening there.

Comment: When I am opening the page from the browser its opening without any issues.  Not sure why only this application is throwing error in the server.

Comment: Is the site expecting user credentials?

Comment: Yes.. Its a single sign on application.